# Adding then removing a class to an achor element on a JavaScript timer

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to be able to cycle anchor selection using jQuery 1.4.4.

The following works when targetting LI elements:

HTML:

```
<ul class="rotating-banner">
    <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript (against jQuery 1.4.4):

```
rotateBanner = function() {
    var active = $('ul.rotating-banner li.active');
    var next = active.next();
    if (next.length === 0) {
        next = $('ul.rotating-banner li:first');
    }

    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}
setInterval(rotateBanner, 1000);
```

This can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Carnotaurus2/Yq9AA/

However, as I said, I wish to target the nested anchor tags across all the LI elements in the UL element (there can only be one anchor tag in each LI element). So, for example, at the first tick interval, we have the first anchor tag selected:

```
<ul class="rotating-banner">
    <li><a class="active">1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then at the next interval, we have the second selected:

```
<ul class="rotating-banner">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a class="active">2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
</ul>
```

After the final selection, the first anchor tag is selected *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get to anchor tags, I changed the selectors as such:

```
var active = $('ul.rotating-banner li a.active');
var next = active.parent().next().find('a');
```

Here a working fiddle (that cycles indefinitely): http://jsfiddle.net/Yq9AA/1/

I missed the *ad infinitum* part, updated my fiddle (this cycles only once): http://jsfiddle.net/Yq9AA/2/

Comment: isn't that what you asked for? also not sure why you din't mark this as answer.

Comment: It stops after a single cycle; instead of cycling forever.

Comment: Well, my first revision cycles indefinitely: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq9AA/1/. In your post, you said "_After the final selection, the first anchor tag is selected ad infinitum_", hence the second revision.

Comment: Please integrate jsfiddle.net/Yq9AA/1 in your answer and it's yours.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I don't get marks for well-formed questions

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
rotateBanner = function() {
    var active = $('ul.rotating-banner a.active');
    var next = active.parent().next();
    if (next.length === 0) {
        next = $('ul.rotating-banner a:first');
    }
    else{
        next = next.find("a");
    }

    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}
setInterval(rotateBanner, 1000);
```